# Converting MIDI-deltatimes to seconds

Tags: midi, milliseconds

my goal is to retrieve the exact note on/off timings from a Standard-MIDI-File. 
The file is type 1 (it has several tracks) and timing mode is ticks-per-quarter.

My approach:

1. I search for setTempo-Events in every track and put them all into a list. I also store the number of ticks between succeeding setTempo-Events in my list.
2. Then I add up all the deltaTimes for each event and obtain the absolute number of ticks relative to tick zero for each event.
3. Finally I calculate the time in seconds from the absolute number of ticks and the list that contains the tempi

Is that a correct way for obtaining note-onsets from a MIDI-file, or do i have to consider the time-signature too? - is the data from the setTempo-event microseconds/quarter or microseconds/beat?

Another question: 
Assuming I got a file with two tracks. Track two has only 1 event at the very end of the file, lets say with deltatime=1000. Track one has two setTempo-Event, one with deltatime=0 and the other with deltatime=500.

Which tempo is used to wait the 1000 ticks in track two - the first tempo, the second or both?

Answer (score 3):

The general stategy I've used is:

1. Record all tempo changes in a list.
2. For each tempo change, use the previous tempo and its real time to calculate the real time of that tempo change. This will result in a list of tempo "intervals" that have a start time in ticks and a start time in seconds
3. For each event, determine which tempo interval it falls in, and calculate its real time since the beginning of the tempo interval

If you're doing all the processing at once, in-order, determining which interval the note falls in is fairly trivial once you have the intervals built.

For your second question - all previous tempos will affect the real time of an event. The above strategy will account for all of that.